# Print certain number of lines from file

Tags: python, for-loop

I have an assignment that involves reading and printing lines from files. I am on a problem right now where I have to print the first `n` amount of lines from the file.

I have a for-loop setup that I thought would do this for me, but it is giving me a `ValueError`. I may just not understand how the for-loop works in Python. I am used to Java and C++ programming.

This is the loop I have set up that I thought would give me the number of lines I want from the file.

```
for i, line in open_file:
    if i > desired_number_of_lines:
        break
    print(line)
```

Does the `i` variable not act as a counter in this case that just counts from 0? This is the error I am receiving when running the program.

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What is `open_file` ?

Comment: Did you want `enumerate(open_file)`? Where did you expect the index to come from?

Comment: @ChihebNexus `open_file` is a variable I setup that stores the opened file. I didn't include it because I don't think it is relevant to the problem. The variable was initialized with this line: `open_file = open(filename, "r")`

Comment: @BrentMB in this case you can do `for index, line in enumerate(open_file.readlines()): ....`

Comment: @BrentMB You should use a context manager to handle that file object.

Comment: @ChihebNexus I used `enumerate(open_file)` and that worked. If I call `.readlines()`, it prints character-by-character

Comment: @BrentMB _If I call .readlines(), it prints character-by-character_ Please show exactly where you're calling `.readlines()`.

Comment: "I didn't include it because I don't think it is relevant to the problem." But now we cannot test your code and have to guess what's missing. Not-working code is fine but it must be self-contained.